# perl equivalent of PHP's $_SESSION

Tags: php, perl

php was a nice experiment, but the language seems inferior.  so, I am thinking of converting my modest codebase from php to perl.

however, some php aspects are worthy of keeping--if only to make code translation easier.  The most important are `$_SERVER`, `$_POST`, `$_GET` and especially `$_SESSION`.

`start_session()` and then the `$_SESSION` hash (ahem, associative array) have immediate assignability.  perl6's CGI::Session has much of the functionality but not the same syntax.  I am assuming that CGI::Session is still the most common and trouble-free module.  I think I will need something like

```
our $_SESSION;
## iterate over the session; docs don't say how; maybe
foreach ($session->param) {  $_SESSION[$_]= session->param($_); }
## and now trap all deaths to call save_param
```

or perhaps a Tie functionality?  or perhaps this already exists as a module other than CGI::Session?!

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: While I salute your bravery, do try to avoid re-inventing the wheel. Frameworks like [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org) and [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) are already implemented and ready to go. Writing your own framework might be educational, but the results are often unusable because of how risky running untested, untrusted code on the public internet is.

Comment: yes for primary work.  no for the occasional user (like me) who only uses it once a year for small projects.  there is too much to learn and remember.  in such cases, a more minimalist structure is better.

Comment: I cannot help but note that some novice programmers get sucked into php (yikes) by the easy beginnings.  framework requirements are an early stopper.  I can think of no php advantages over perl other than the easier entry when used without framework.

Comment: "Too much to learn" is all about where your focus will be. You can get a lot done by half-understanding a framework, it'll have your back. You will make a giant mess of things if you only half-understand the language and are programming from first principles. I have never seen that turn out well.

Comment: another problem with a framework is that perl does not have one, but many.  so, I will need peers who happen to know the specific framework.  it's almost like choosing a language.  perl is a standard that I can expect many others to know.  php is the most widely used language on the web---and not because it is good.  it can be used by someone who writes a 500-line web app once every 2 years, and works on other things the rest of the time.

Comment: PHP's other best and worst feature is that so much of what would require using a CPAN module in perl is in PHP already. If you are on a simple shared host, or don't have control over your server it's quite fiddly for a novice to get those perl modules installed.

Answer (score 2):

PHP as used on websites is a language and also a web framework, albeit a very simple one. So if you are choosing perl you will also need to choose a perl web library/framework. I would recommend http://mojolicious.org/ personally, but you will see lots of older code using CGI.pm which was great back in the day, but will seem very low level these days.

Here's a nice quick summary here of [alternatives to CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.14/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm).

Comment: mojolicious is great, but the learning curve is high and the underlying code base is still changing.  simulating $_SESSION is a very low-level substitute that can, at least for smaller projects, be useful.

Comment: You really don't want to use `CGI.pm` in 2016. It's from an era when requirements were significantly simpler and people weren't that intent on causing harm.

Comment: As I said I don't recommend new code use the CGI.pm module these days as it's so low level compared to Mojo etc., but the CGI.pm is probably fairly secure though, I'll wager more secure than these newer frameworks. Look how many security fixes it's had over the years

Comment: let's say I just want to request and record a user's email, store it on a file on the computer, and show it at the top of the page.  would you really use a full framework?  crank up complexity just a little.  say one form.  now a framework?  there is a tradeoff.  at some simple enough point, frameworks are probably not the right solution.

Comment: Take a look at the link I've added, it compares using CGI,pm (probably what you mean by using no framework?) vs the alertnatives